# React Native: "Google Chrome exited with error..." after scan the QR code

Tags: react-native

I have just started to use React Native. Everything was going ok, but now Im getting this error after scanning the QR code using Expo:
[image]

I get also this error in Expo:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, nodejs 7.10, and an external device connected. 
I have restarted Ubuntu and my phone, but the error persists.

Ubuntu recognizes my phone after running `adb devices`.

I can give you more information about my settings if you ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error just now. Reinstalling Expo on my phone then installing `chromium` using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` did the trick.